# How to open ports for dedicated servers?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, dedicated-server

I've been trying to create a dedicated server for Project Zomboid for a while now, but I always get stuck with Port Forwarding. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I do everything correctly on the router, but when I check if the port is open it appears as closed. This problem is preventing me from playing online with my friends.

I'm using "you get signal" to check the port status.

How do I open a port on my router? What is "local port from", "local port to", "remote port from", "remote port to" and "remote ip"?

My Router Picture:

[image: My Router Picture]

Comment: Sounds like your behind a CGNAT

Answer (score -1):

To open ports for your dedicated server:

- Access your router's settings by entering its IP address in a web browser.
- Log in using your router's username and password.
- Navigate to the port forwarding or virtual server section.
- Add a new port forwarding rule.
- Enter the port details:

1. Local Port From" and "Local Port To" specify the range of ports on your local network.
2. Remote Port From" and "Remote Port To" specify the range of ports on the remote server.
3. Remote IP" specifies the IP address of the device on the remote network.

- Save your changes and apply the new port forwarding rule.
- Check the port status using a tool like "You Get Signal" to ensure it's open.
- Test your server to see if it's accessible from outside your local network.

If you're still having issues, double-check your port forwarding settings and consult your router's manual for further assistance.